# Runtime error with GLSL shaders: Inconsistency detected by ld.so

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am writing some OpenGL code to draw a small dot in a window, but when I try to use my own shaders, I get an error message which I don't understand.

So, here's my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Initialize some things
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Test");
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
    glewInit();
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Make the vertex buffer
    Vector3f vertices[1];
    vertices[0] = Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Main GLUT loop
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

And here's my rendering callback function:

```
static void RenderScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

This compiles and runs fine, displaying a small white dot against a black background, as expected.

Now, I want to use my own shaders instead of the default ones. So, in the main function, just before `glutMainLoop()`, I include the line:

```
MakeShaderProgram("vertex-shader.glsl");
```

And this function is defined as:

```
static void MakeShaderProgram(std::string shader_filename)
{
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    const GLchar* ptr_filename = &shader_filename[0];
    const GLchar** ptr_filenames = &ptr_filename;
    int filename_lengths[] = {1};
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, ptr_filenames, &filename_lengths[0]);
    glCompileShader(shader);
    glAttachShader(program, shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glUseProgram(program);
}
```

Finally, the file "vertex-shader.glsl", which is located in the same directory as the executable, has the following contents:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(0.5 * Position.x, 0.5 * Position.y, Position.z, 1.0);
}
```

Now, compiling this is fine. However, on running it, I receive the following error:

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-version.c: 224: _dl_check_map_versions: Assertion `needed != ((void *)0)' failed!
```

The program breaks right after the main function starts. I have no idea what this error message means, but it is caused by attempting to use my own shaders rather than the default shaders.

Can somebody explain what is going wrong?

If it is relevant, here is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

project(OpenGLTest)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR})

file(GLOB SRCS *.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRCS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARY} ${GLUT_LIBRARY})
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a Ubuntu bug. The short version is, that Ubuntu messed some up their OpenGL packages and introduced a dependency on pthread, even in programs that are not using pthread at all. The simple workaround solution is to add pthread to the list of libraries to be linked.

The bug gets triggered if a non-packaged OpenGL implementation gets used (like the AMD/ATI or NVidia proprietary drivers).

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-319/+bug/1248642