# Declaration of std::string causes a segmentation fault with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Consider a very simple OpenGL program:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

static void RenderScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Test");
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
    glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.0f);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs fine, displaying a grey window as expected.

Then, I introduce three variables into the main function, before the OpenGL processing. The code becomes:

```
#include <string>
#include <GL/glut.h>


static void RenderScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x = 5;
    char y = 'a';
    std::string z = "abc";

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Test");
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
    glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.0f);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this is fine, but if I run it, I receive a segmentation fault error. Now, if I comment out the line `std::string z = "abc";`, then it runs fine without any errors.

So, for some reason, declaring a string variable is causing a segmentation fault here, but not with any other variable types.

If I remove all the OpenGL code, then it runs fine. But if I remove all the OpenGL code except for just one line, such as `glutInit(&argc, argv);`, then it still causes the segmentation fault.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: I had a similar problem once.  I found adding glutGet(GLUT_DISPLAY_MODE_POSSIBLE) (and exiting if it returned false) helped.  It felt like the glutGet() was performing some essential initialization.  But I never was able to actually trace it down and prove it.

Comment: are you calling with commandline arguments?

Comment: include compiler name, version & platform

Comment: Also looking at your other probably related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949880/runtime-error-with-glsl-shaders-inconsistency-detected-by-ld-so, it almost looks like you have a problem with the standard C++ library on your system. Maybe the headers you include and the library that gets linked/loaded do not match, or something in that style.

Comment: seems to be a duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579243/segmentation-fault-before-main-when-using-glut-and-stdstring

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problem too, but mine was on Linux. Is your on Linux or Windows? Do you have any graphic card driver install?

For my case, I'm running on `Ubuntu` with `nVidia` installed, I notice that when I link my program with `libGL.so` located at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, it will cause segmentation fault. Then I also found out there is another `libGL.so` located at `/usr/lib/nvidia-352`, this will link without crash.

Hope this help.