# Unreachable glXMakeCurrent crashes c++ application

Tags: c++, opengl, nvidia, glx

usually I am able to solve almost all my programming questions on my own, but this one really amazes me and I guess you will also find it very interesting.

So I am working on a low level OpenGL application using GLX and it crashes with a segmentation fault. I have broken the code down to this minimal example:

```
#include <string>
#include <GL/glx.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Display* display = NULL;
    if(display)
        glXMakeCurrent(display, 0, 0);
    std::string title("Hello GLX");
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with

```
g++ -g -o wtf wtf.cpp -lGL
```

I am using 64 bit Linux Mint 17.3 by the way.

As you can see, there is nothing suspicious - I mean it doesn't even do anything, but as I said, it crashes... The Segfault disappears if I comment out the `glXMakeCurrent` which makes absolutely no sense, because that isn't even ever reached.
It also doesn't crash if I remove the instantiation of the string. Swapping the instantiations or the includes doesn't help, it still crashes.

Here is a GDB Backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff3deb291 in init () at dlerror.c:177
#2  0x00007ffff3deb6d7 in _dlerror_run (operate=operate@entry=0x7ffff3deb130 <dlsym_doit>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffffdc50)
    at dlerror.c:129
#3  0x00007ffff3deb198 in __dlsym (handle=<optimized out>, name=<optimized out>) at dlsym.c:70
#4  0x00007ffff7b4ee1e in ?? () from /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so.1
#5  0x00007ffff7af9b47 in ?? () from /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so.1
#6  0x00007ffff7dea0cd in call_init (l=0x7ffff7ff94c0, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffdda8, 
    env=env@entry=0x7fffffffddb8) at dl-init.c:64
#7  0x00007ffff7dea1f3 in call_init (env=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, argc=<optimized out>, l=<optimized out>)
    at dl-init.c:36
#8  _dl_init (main_map=0x7ffff7ffe1c8, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdda8, env=0x7fffffffddb8) at dl-init.c:126
#9  0x00007ffff7ddb30a in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#10 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007fffffffe101 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

and my `glxinfo` output (except for the extensions)

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
...
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx version string: 1.4
...
GLX version: 1.4
...
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 560 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.0 NVIDIA 352.63
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
...
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 352.63
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
```

I am really amazed by this, because IMHO it makes absolutely no sense. Does one of you have an idea what the problem could be? I was thinking that some call might have corrupted the classes VTable, but in this example there aren't even classes. It's also not an 32-vs-64-bit conflict with libGL.so.

When I put an `std::cerr << "foo";` and `std::cerr.flush();` (to be sure although it shouldn't be necessary) at the beginning of the main function, I get no output, so it seems like a problem with loading the library, but I can run the code from opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.0_Context_Creation_(GLX), so the problem cannot be the discovery of the library or the graphics chip being in some faulty state or so (I even rebooted... a linux machine... that's how out of ideas I am!)

Comment: Have you tried stepping the code in a debugger and watching the values of the variables during that time? Also, what happens when you change the call to `glXMakeCurrent(0, 0, 0);`? And when you change the condition to `if (false)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [Segmentation Fault before main() when using glut, and std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579243/segmentation-fault-before-main-when-using-glut-and-stdstring)
The workaround there works for me also: forcing libpthread to be linked, for example by

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
./wtf
```

Still one of the most bizarre and illogical problems I have ever encountered.

Comment: You're using Mint. Mint is derived from Ubuntu. This is a Ubuntu bug. Somewhere in the build configuration of Ubuntu the Xlib is improperly linked against pthread which leads to this bizarre problem. It's been open in the bug tracker for ages and apparently nobody can be bothered to fix it properly.